# Doing sums with full joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with the following data:

```
create table #CompanyA (
ID varchar(50), 
tran_count int
)

insert into #CompanyA
values 
('A', 1),
('B',4)


create table #CompanyB (
ID varchar(50),
tran_count int
)

insert into #CompanyB
values ('A',5),
       ('C',3)
```

and i'm trying to write a select joining the two tables by ID column, and that will add the respective tran_counts by ID. I tried doing this by using a full join, but I don't know how to account for the NULL values:

```
    Select A.ID, B.ID, A.tran_count, B.tran_count, A.tran_count + B.tran_count as total
    from #CompanyA A full join #CompanyB B
    on A.ID = B.ID

      ID    ID    tran_count    tran_count  total
       A    A     1             5           6
       B    NULL  4             NULL        NULL
       NULL C     NULL          3           NULL
```

The desired output I want is this:

```
 ID sumtotal
 A  6
 B  4
 C  3
```

Please let me know!

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Did you get the desired output?

Comment: Check out `ISNULL`, I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: ISNULL works for about half of what I want: 

  Select A.ID, B.ID, A.tran_count, B.tran_count,                   ISNULL(A.tran_count,0) + ISNULL(B.tran_count,0) as total
  from #CompanyA A full join #CompanyB B
  on A.ID = B.ID

This does not combine the 'ID' fields, however; I'm looking for a way to return 

ID
A
B
C,

not two separate ID columns. I want all distinct ID values in one list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DECODE function.
Try this:

```
DECODE(field,NULL,0, field)
```

Comment: Sql server doesn't have this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all null values with any of your choising with [isNull()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

In your example, the query would look like this.

```
Select A.id as ID, isnull(A.tran_count,0) + isnull(B.tran_count,0) as sumtotal
    from #CompanyA A full join #CompanyB B
    on A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: This does exactly what I'm looking for:

with Z as (Select A.id as ID, isnull(A.tran_count,0) + isnull(B.tran_count,0) as sumtotal
    from #CompanyA A full join #CompanyB B
    on A.ID = B.ID
 UNION 
Select B.id as ID, isnull(A.tran_count,0) + isnull(B.tran_count,0) as sumtotal
    from #CompanyA A full join #CompanyB B
    on A.ID = B.ID)
    
select * from Z where ID is not null

But this is also quite messy! Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not "union all" the two tables and sum the tran_count? From the sample you have given this should work

```
select id, sum(tran_count) as sumtotal
from
(
select id,tran_count
from #CompanyA
union all
select id,tran_count
from #CompanyB
) a
group by id
```

Comment: Yup, that's essentially what I ended up doing to fix the problem. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this besides subqueries/CTEs along with a union all, but this works.

Comment: Why on earth would you not consider this a clean solution?